# MongoDB empty collection before insert document into db

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to implement a function to empty the collection every time I populate document into the database. This doesn't work for me. I also tried using `async.series`, but still no luck. Why doesn't this code below work? The output always with `db.users.find().count()` gave me `0`.

```
function emptyThenInsert(db) {
  UserSchema.collection.remove({}, function(err) {
    if(err) console.log(err);
    UserSchema.collection.insert(db, function(err, data) {
      console.log(data);
      if (err) console.log(err);
      UserSchema.collection.find({}, function(err, data) {
        console.log(data);
        if (err) console.log(err);
      });
    });
  });
}
```

It works if I take out `UserSchema.collection.remove`.

Comment: Have you tried collection.drop()? it's fastest way to empty collection rather than individual document.

Comment: I tried it, still doesn't work. @Saleem not sure why it doesn't call `insert` after `remove`.

Comment: Can you explain why you try to insert 'db' and not a document or array of documents?

Comment: `db` is just a document name. I can change it to `doc` or something else. @MauritsRijk

Comment: How is `UserSchema` defined?

Comment: This is quite difficult to guess without seeing more context. Maybe your program exits directly after the call to emptyThenInsert. Since you don't wait for that call to finish, that would explain why you never see the insert happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seem to work for me.

```
function emptyThenInsert(db) {
  UserSchema.remove({}, function(err) {
    if(err) console.log(err);
    UserSchema.collection.insert(db, function(err, data) {
      if (err) console.log(err);
      UserSchema.collection.find({}, function(err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
      });
      process.exit(1);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Were you able to discover why it didn't work at first?

Comment: If you could provide a little description, it would help the next person that views this solution.

Comment: Maybe the difference between `UserSchema.collection.remove` and `UserSchema.remove` and I also add `process.exit(1)` after insertion completed. @gnerkus

Answer (score 0):

Try to use write concern:

```
UserSchema.collection.insert(db, {w:1}, function(err, data) {
```